# Whats Best way to Model following Mongodb Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have 2 models like this

```
const testRunSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    testTimeSlot: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    testDate: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    diagnosticData: [Object],
    notes: String,
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    strict: false
})

const testingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    testId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },

    testDetails: {
        //dummy data
    },
    contactDetails: {
        //dummy data
    },
    testRunDetails: [testRunSchema], //is this a best way?
    runByAssistant: Boolean
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Testing', testingSchema)
```

Now i want to access the `testTimeSlot` (which is first model) using the `testId` of the second model.

My Solution:

I can access the `testimeSlot` of first model, using `testId` because data of first model is available in `testRunDetails` of seconf model.

Problem With this solution:

Since `testRunSchema` is defined as a array in second model, its not easy and efficient to access the `testTimeSlot` of every array element.

What is the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

what you thought is correct it's not easy to access them besides the more the array gets filled the slower the query will be. So it would be better if  you separate the testRunSchema and save the reference of it's data in to the testingSchema

```
const testingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    testId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },

    testDetails: {
        //dummy data
    },
    contactDetails: {
        //dummy data
    },
    testRunDetails:{
          type:[Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref:'testRunSchema'
    },//like this in here the object id of testRunSchema 

    runByAssistant: Boolean
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

when you want to query, you just need to use polulate() in mongoose 
you can read it in [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: whats the differece between `testRunDetails: [Schema.Types.ObjectId]` and `testRunDetails: [{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'testRunSchema'}]`

Comment: the ref tells us what model to use when populating

Comment: sorry I forgot to put it in the answer. check it now i have edited it. Hope this helped

Comment: `ref` key word should be inside right? `testRunDetails: [{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'testRunSchema'}]`

Comment: yeah it should be